# laravel add scheduler dynamically

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

I have a system where the user can create background tasks via the UI.
The task interval are every few hours (user choice in the UI).

when the user creates a task via the ui i want to add it to the scheduler dynamically.

As the example states, this is static and not dynamic.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        DB::table('recent_users')->delete();
    })->daily();
}
```

Is it possible? if not, what are the alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 26):

I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. The `Kernel::schedule` method will be run every time `php artisan schedule:run` is run. If you set it up like the documentation, should be every minute via a cron.

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

With that in mind, I don't see why you can't do something like this:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // Get all tasks from the database
    $tasks = Task::all();

    // Go through each task to dynamically set them up.
    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        // Use the scheduler to add the task at its desired frequency
        $schedule->call(function() use($task) {
            // Run your task here
            $task->execute();
        })->cron($task->frequency);
    }
}
```

Depending on what you store, you can use whatever you like here instead of the CRON method. You might have a string stored in your database that represents one of Laravel's predefined frequencies and in which case you could do something like this:

```
$frequency = $task->frequency; // everyHour, everyMinute, twiceDaily etc.
$schedule->call(function() {
    $task->execute();
})->$frequency();
```

The main thing to note here, is that the schedule isn't actually scheduling in tasks in the database or in a cron that it manages. Every time the scheduler runs (Every minute) it runs and it determines what to run based on the frequencies you give each task.

**Example:**

- You have a task set up using `->hourly()`, that is, to run on the hour, every hour.
- At `00:00`, the schedule runs, the `->hourly()` filter passes, because the time is on the hour, so your task runs.
- At `00:01`, the schedule runs and but this time the `->hourly()` filter fails, so your task does not run.

Comment: I got it working with reusable Commands (the only downside is have to use the same # of params as the Command you define and not truly dynamically send whatever params you want which the GUI allows ... However I think that is fine since my Command would have to know what params are coming in anyway and have a pre-set # defined in the $signature). Thanks so much for explaining how to do this... Here is my code so far: https://github.com/armyofda12mnkeys/laravel-task-gui-linkage