# Assign date/time to Task scheduler dynamically without database query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I have a task that requires the use of Laravel Task Scheduler. I already implemented the basic set up for the scheduler. The only thing remaining is setting the custom cron schedule. Custom Cron Schedule values will come from user input. For example, the user sets up start and end dates. I will use the inputted data to set up task scheduler.

So what I did so far is to use Events/Listeners to extract the dates upon saving then pass it to Kernel class. The thing is when I pass it to the Kernel class and log the date property assigned, when the schedule:run runs in the crontab the log displays null. **Is there anyway of passing the saved dates to the scheduler and use it for custom cron schedule w/o querying the database?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel add scheduler dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801334/laravel-add-scheduler-dynamically)

Comment: @Jon The task requires user input and set the scheduler without querying