# Laravel 5.6 Delete schedules in the code

Tags: php, rest, laravel-5, schedule

## I have a API where a user create integrations.

#### Those integrations may have recurrence (repeat every 6 months, every 2 days, etc).

- In the UI when the user selects when to repeat is generated a cron (ex: * * * * *).
- The recurrence is managed by the laravel schedule (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling)
- That cron is saved in the configurations of that integration of the user

#### EX: then in the Kernel.php :

```
$schedule->job(new IntegrateJob, 'integrationId')->cron('* * * * *');
```

Easy... I works!!!

But if the user deletes the integrations (soft delete), then I dont want to run that job in the selected cron.

## I want to delete that entry in the laravel scheduler.

But that info is not saved anywhere, not in the database, not in cache, not in the redis server that manages the jobs...

If I cant find them I cant delete them... Any Solutions? Thank U

Comment: Did you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38803558/2779152) - specifically this text _"The main thing to note here, is that the schedule isn't actually scheduling in tasks in the database or in a cron that it manages. Every time the scheduler runs (Every minute) it runs and it determines what to run based on the frequencies you give each task._

Comment: I understand, so what I am doing is kinda correct. I get in the kernel all the integrations configs. And then schedule call the job if any

Comment: Maybe Im not understanding your question, but your asking how to delete a scheduled task in Laravel?

Comment: I just wanted to the jobs stopped running, no I understand that If I delete the conf table when the integration table is deleted (cascade) the schedule will no work. Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper way to do this would be changing your design so the event runs for all the users and then determines which user(s) to run the event for (if any). Also, the way Laravel handles scheduled tasks in different than the way Linux handles Cron jobs.

As an example:

If you have the following code in the `app/Console/Kernel.php` file and run  `php artisan schedule:run`, the job is ran.

```
$schedule->job(new IntegrateJob, 'integrationId')->cron('* * * * *');
```

If you take out the above code and run `php artisan schedule:run` after a minute, the job will not be ran because Laravel does not persist the job.

Comment: The client requires to allow the user to choose when the requirement is run. So I don't see how what you are saying solves the problem

Comment: I suggest you do a bit more research into Laravel and understand how the task scheduling works.