# Laravel - Schedule job for each premium users

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling

### What I need to do

When user purchase premium, I give him premium money. Every week, I need to give premium money again at subscription time. However, if the user is no longer a subscriber, they should no longer receive their premium money.

### Questions

I think I need to use scheduled tasks, but I do not know how to do that on right way.

1. How to add tasks dynamically ?
2. Do I need to put the tasks in the database tasks table ?
3. How to remove task if user is unsubscribed ? (the check is made in my job but how to remove the task if is unsubscribe)

### Code

I need to run this task.

```php
   $schedule->job(new CreditPremiumUser($userId))-> weeklyOn(1, '10:42:53');
   // 1 = premium purchase day
   // '10:42:53' = subscription time
```

Comment: I would simply create one job that run every week, that get all premium users from database and give them the credits, i don't think there is a need to handle subscription time, you could give the credits at midnight for everyone

Comment: If you want you can even make the diff between subscription datetime, and current datetime, and if it's less than 7 days, give partial credits

Comment: @Lk77 It is not possible because each user does not subscribe at same dateTime. If user subscribe Saturday at 10:43, the user would have his premium money Saturday at 10:43 and the next Monday. It would be credited twice in 2 days

Comment: It won't be credited twice, only on monday at midnight, there is only one job that run on monday at midnight and that's all, when user subscribe he gets nothing until monday

Comment: If user subscribe, he want his premium money directly  If i do your solution, user sub during 1 month can have just 3 weeks of premium money instead of 4 weeks

Comment: Why not run the same job every minute. Then within the controller method you can work out who needs to be credited at that time/day of the week? Instead of passing in parameters like you are here, get all the information you need within the method?

Comment: @Luke I think it is not good to run job who get all premium users and check if each premium user need to be credited every minutes. I think we can optimise the process

Comment: You can do every 5 minutes it's fine

Comment: It is not a good solution to run code to fetch all premium users and check each one if he need to be credited each 5 minutes. I think we can do something with tasks scheduler

Comment: But you're going to have to query all of the premium users at some point anyway in order to be able to do some sort of funky foreach loop through them within the schedular? Which I guess is what you're planning on doing? (and doesn't sound wise at all)
Unless you're planning to write a new line of code manually into the schedular for each new premium user?

Comment: What I am thinking to do is: When user subscribe, credit the user and initialise scheduled task to credit him every week at same dataTime. For each new user subscription add new scheduled task.

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38803558/11761437
I need to have tasks table in my DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What i did

#### Create table tasks

```php
  Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->id();
     $table->string('type'); // optional
     $table->string('frequency_function');
     $table->string('frequency_params')->nullable(); // optional
     $table->string('job_name')->nullable(); // optional
     $table->integer('user_id')->nullable(); // optional
     $table->timestamps();
   });
   /*
     Example task data
       type = 'subscription_credit'
       frequency_function = 'weeklyOn'
       frequency_params = 'a:2:{i:0;i:3;i:1;s:5:"12:20";}' // serialize(array(3, '12:20'))
       job_name = App/Jobs/Premium/CreditPremiumMoney
       user_id = 1
   */
```

I need to schedule Job so I have `job_name` column.


For example, depending on your needs, you can add `command_name` column if you want to schedule the execution of a command.

#### Update Kernel

In your **App\Console\Kernel.php** `schedule` method write:

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $tasks = Task::all();
    
    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        $type = $task->type; // optional
        $frequencyFunc = $task->frequency_function;
        $frequencyFuncParams = $task->frequency_params
            ? unserialize($task->frequency_params)
            : [];
        
        if ($type === 'subscription_credit') { // optional
            $job = $task->job_name;
            $userId = $task->user_id;
            $schedule->job(new $job($userId), 'low', 'redis')
                ->$frequencyFunc(...$frequencyFuncParams);
        } else if ($type === '...') {
            // Other optional type logic
        }
    }
}
```

You can remove `type` condition if you do not need it or add multiple types logic if you need type.

#### Try It

Add all your tasks to your database.


**Local**

Run command `php artisan schedule:work` and the scheduler will run to process your tasks at the scheduled dataTime


**Production**

Add CRON to your server like [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler)


On each environment, the scheduler will run every minute and check if there are tasks to execute in `tasks` table.